# Extracting Real Part of Twiddle Factors from `fftw_plan`

Tags: fftw, chebyshev

When calculating a type-II DCT with FFTW, you create an `fftw_plan`, via

`fftw_plan plan = fftw_plan_r2r_1d(size, in_ptr, out_ptr, FFTW_REDFT10, FFTW_ESTIMATE);`

As I understand it, the plan precomputes the twiddle factors so that the plan can be efficiently reused for multiple calls to `fftw_execute_r2r(plan, in_ptr, out_ptr)`.

Since I'm trying to calculate
\begin{align*}
c_{k} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} f\left(\cos\left(\frac{(j+1/2)\pi}{N}\right)\right) \cos\left(\frac{(j+1/2)k\pi}{N}\right)
\end{align*}
I figure that the `fftw_plan` already has computed the argument to $f$, so I don't want to recompute it.

How do you extract the twiddle factors from the `fftw_plan`?